# Cohomological dimension of continuous étale cohomology of finitely generated fields

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, etale-cohomology, cohomological-dimension

Given a finitely generated field $F$ with prime field $k$, we assume $k$ is finite, of characteristic $p$. Fix a prime $\ell$ invertible in $k$.

In the discussion right after [K, Lemma 2.3], the variant

$$H^{*,\star}:=\tilde{\rm H}^*_{\rm cont}(\text{Spec}(F)/\text{Spec}(k),\mathbf{Z}_{\ell}(\star))$$ of Jannsen's continuous étale cohomology of $\text{Spec}(F)$ is defined, for integers $(*,\star)$, with $*$ nonnegative (notation as in loc cit, with $X = \text{Spec}(F)$ and $S = \text{Spec}(k)$).

A more explicit description of $H^{*,\star}$ can be given, as per loc cit, as follows.

Write $F$ as a filtered colimit of the global complete intersection $k$-subalgebras $A$ of $F$ (see [SP, [Tag 07BV](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/07BV))], and denote by ${\rm H}_{\rm cont}^*(\text{Spec}(A),\mathbf{Z}_{\ell}(\star))$ the continuous étale cohomology of Jannsen's.

**Remark.** Here $\mathbf{Z}_{\ell}(\star)$ is the pro-sheaf $\{\mu_{\ell^n}^{\otimes\star}, n\ge 1\}$, as per construction of Jannsen's continuous étale cohomology. See [J] for details on continuous étale cohomology, and [K, $\S$2] for an overview. Roughly, continuous étale cohomology of a scheme $X$ with coefficients in the pro-sheaf $\mathbf{Z}_{\ell}(\star)$ is, degree-wise, an extension of usual $\ell$-adic cohomology of $X$ by a $\lim^1$ module.

Then the $H^{*,\star}$ from above can be written as
$$H^{*,\star} = \varinjlim_{k\subset A\subset F}{\rm H}_{\rm cont}^*(\text{Spec}(A),\mathbf{Z}_{\ell}(\star)).$$

Now define
$$H^{*,\star}_{\mathbf{Q}} := H^{*,\star}\otimes_{\mathbf{Z}}\mathbf{Q}.$$

> **Question.**  Why does $H^{i,p}_{\mathbf{Q}}$ vanish for $i>p+1$, regardless of the transcendence degree of $F$?

**Example.** When $F$ is a *finite* extension of $k$, then we get
$$H^{*,\star} = {\rm H}^*_{\rm cont}(F,\mathbf{Z}_{\ell}(\star)).$$
Here the right side is continuous cohomology of the field $F$ as in [J, Thm. 3.2]. Since $F$, in this example, is finite, we get that, for all integers $p$, $H^{i,p}$ is zero for all $i\neq 1$, and finite for $i=1$, so $H^{i,p}_{\mathbf{Q}}=0$ for all $i$.

**Remark.** From [K, Cor.6.10(b)] we can already deduce that, writing $d$ for the transcendence degree of $F$ over $k$, we have $H^{i,p}_{\mathbf{Q}}=0$ for $i\notin [p,p+d+1]$. If $F$ is separable, the same corollary implies the vanishing for $i\notin[p,2p+1]$, since we can arrange every $A$ from above to be a localization of a $k$-smooth subalgebra of $F$, and ${\rm H}^i_{\rm cont}(\text{Spec}(A),\mathbf{Z}_{\ell}(p))$ is finite for $i\notin [p,2p+1]$. The question is asking if the vanishing holds already for $i > p+1$. According to [K, Thm.8.18], this is a consequence of the Tate Conjecture. The Theorem is more precise though, and *the question is asking for less*: it only asks if this vanishing is already known to hold, and what's an argument/a reference.

**References:**

[J] U. Jannsen, *Continuous étale cohomology*. Math. Annalen.
[K] B. Kahn, *A sheaf-theoretic  reformulation of the Tate conjecture*. [Preprint](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9801017.pdf).
[SP] [Stacks Project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/07BV).

Comment: Are you meaning to take a limit as $n$ goes to $\infty$? If not, won't the group be $l^n$-torsion and then vanish after you tensor with $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: Yes the continuous part means considering the projective system of roots of unity as $n$ goes to infinity.

Comment: I think this question is probably unknown without the Tate conjecture. Suppose there did exist an $X$ with a Tate class in degree $2p$ that did not come from an algebraic cycle. Take $K$ to be the field of fractions of $X$, it is a limit over open subsets of $X$. I don't see any reason why this cohomology class should vanish after passing to an open subset. So it will give continuous cohomology in degrees $2p$ and $2p+1$ for each open subset.